# Display plain text in a QTextBrowser using QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have some json data in QTableView that I want to display in QTextEdit, I use QDataWidgetMapper to map the data,
I found that the data displayed in DisplayRole is normal, but in EditRole, the spaces and line breaks are removed when displaying. I tried QLabel, and QTextEdit did not achieve the effect.

this is demo:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import json, sys

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datas):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._datas = datas

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            data = self._datas[row][col]
            if col == self.columnCount() - 1:
                data = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
            return data

        elif role == Qt.EditRole:  #
            data = self._datas[row][col]
            if col == self.columnCount() - 1:
                data = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
            return data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._datas)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self._datas[0])


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mapper = None

        datas = [
            ('a1', {'a': 111, 'b': [1, 2]}),
            ('a2', {'a': 222, 'b': [1, 2]}),
        ]
        model = TableModel(datas)

        treeview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        treeview.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        treeview.setModel(model)
        self.nameEdit = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(treeview)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameEdit)

        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit, 1)
        treeview.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywindow = MainWidget()
mywindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass the propertyName to the addMapping method then the properties it will use will be the userProperty, and in the case of QTextBrowser it is html:

```py
print(self.nameEdit.metaObject().userProperty().name())
```

Output:

```
html
```

This explains the problem, the solution is to indicate that the plainText property will be used:

```py
self.mapper.addMapping(self.nameEdit, 1, b"plainText")
```

[image]

Comment: tks for u help, By the way, since QTextBrowser is Html, is it possible to display a scalable json data format in QTextBrowser?

Comment: @Alex What is "scalable json data format"?

Comment: expand&hidden Json data

Comment: @Alex I don't understand you, do you have any article where you got that term from? Anyway I think that is beyond the scope of my answer so I will no longer respond, bye.